# The centroid of a set lies in its convex hull

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls, centroid

I've come across the following claim on a Wikipedia page about the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid):

> The geometric centroid of a convex object always lies in the object

1. How should I prove this claim for convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where the centroid is usually located by using the integral formula?
2. Is it true that more generally, the centroid of a (not necessarily convex) subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ lies in its convex hull?

Comment: @uniquesolution What? All I did was change $R^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $X$ is a closed, convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with positive volume. The centroid of $X$, is by definition the normalized vector-valued integral:
$$c_X=\frac{1}{\text{Vol}(X)}\int_{X}x\,dx$$
The integral here is with respect to the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, as with any integration process, you can find a sequence of partitions of $X$ into small pieces, say, $\{X_{i,m}\}_{i=1}^{N_m}$,
where $X_{i,m}$ are subsets of $X$ with positive volume, such that 
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{N_m}x_{i,m}\text{Vol}(X_{i,m})=\int_X x\,dx$$
where $x_{i,m}$ are points in $X_{i,m}$. Dividing both sides by the volume of $X$ you get
$$\frac{1}{\text{Vol}X}\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{N_m}x_{i,m}\text{Vol}(X_{i,m})= c_X$$
Observe that for each $m$, the sum on the left hand side is a convex combination of the points $x_{i,m}$, because the volumes of $X_{i,m}$ sum up to the volume of $X$. Thus, since $X$ is convex, $c_X$ is a limit of points in $X$, and since $X$ is closed, $c_X$ belongs to $X$.

It is not true that in general the centroid of a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ belongs to $X$. Take, for instance the unit disc in the plane, punctured at its center. The centroid of this set is of course the removed center.

Comment: Could you please explain how I changed the question?

Comment: Also, your set $X$ at the end is not convex so the question remains whether OP's claim holds for convex sets which are not necessarily closed.

Comment: the lebesgue integral is not defined by riemann sums, how can you prove that the limit of such approximations of the Lebesgue Integral by riemann sums is actually the desired Lebesgue Integral?

Comment: i am aware that this is not quite a riemann sum, because the $x_{i,m}\text{Vol}(X_{i,m})$ must add up exactly to $\frac{1}{\text{Vol}X}$,

Answer (score 2):

Actually the correct result is that the centroid of a convex object lies in the closure of the object.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be convex set with positive Lebesgue measure and let $\overline{x}$ be the centroid of $A$. Assume that $\overline{x}\notin \overline{A}$.

Recall [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorem):

> **Hahn-Banach separation theorem** 
>   Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty disjoint convex subsets of a real normed space $X$. If $A$ is open, there exists a bounded linear functional $f \in X'$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(a) < t \le f(b) \quad\text{ for all } a \in A, b \in B$$

Then there exits $r > 0$ such that $A$ and $B(\overline{x},r)$ are disjoint. The theorem implies there exists a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\overline{x}) < t \le f(x)$ for all $x \in A$. Then we have

$$f(\overline{x}) = \frac1{\lambda(A)} f\left(\int_Ax\,dx\right) =  \frac1{\lambda(A)} \int_Af(x)\,dx \ge  \frac1{\lambda(A)} \int_At\,dx = t$$
which contradicts $f(\overline{x}) < t$. Therefore $\overline{x} \in \overline{A}$.

Comment: @Somos You're right, it is impossible. In my defense, I copied that part from uniquesolution's previous answer haha.

Comment: Next time you copy someone else's **deleted** answer you may want to ask yourself why did they chose to delete it. haha.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yeah, I figured your current example was simpler so you decided to put that instead. Anyway, OP's second question remains open.

Comment: thanks! what is the justification for the second equality?

Comment: @David $f$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore \begin{align} f\left(\int_A \mathbf{x}\,d\mathbf{x}\right) &= f\left(\int_A x_1\,d\mathbf{x}, \ldots, \int_A x_n\,d\mathbf{x}\right) \\ &= a_1 \int_A x_1\,d\mathbf{x} + \cdots + a_n\int_A x_n\,d\mathbf{x} \\ &= \int_A(a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n)\,d\mathbf{x} \\ &= \int_A f(x)\,d\mathbf{x}\end{align}

Comment: @mechanodroid thanks!